# Eclipse hanging when i connect an Android device or starting Android Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, android-4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-s

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, Eclipse 3.7.2 and Android SDK with the latest updates.
I develop Android Apps and when i want to start the app on my phone with adb or using the Android Emulator, Eclipse freezes and i can't do anything with eclipse. I hope you can help me.
thanks!

Comment: please give me Error logs from eclipse.

Comment: !SESSION 2012-09-14 14:03:11.364 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=de_DE
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2012-09-14 14:03:14.120
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

Comment: Try change workspace or just reset all settings eclpse. If this is not support, then download Eclipse Juno and use it.

Comment: i already deleted the .eclipse folder in my personal folder but with no effect. Now i'm downloading eclipse juno. Do you know is there a deb package for juno?

Comment: downloads with official site [Juno](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/juno/R/eclipse-jee-juno-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz) - 64 bit version

Comment: Same problem here... Tried all the suggestions and they failed.
Eclipse just hangs waiting for something to happen... any clue/solution?

Comment: i downloaded the juno version of eclipse and that was my solution. Which version of Eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 0):

try to restart adb server

Using kill-server and start-server commands.

Comment: i think problem not adb, problem in eclipse. This is version eclipse have many bugs. May be need change on Juno.

Comment: is there a deb package for eclipse juno?

Comment: downloads with official site [Juno](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/juno/r)

Comment: thank you very much. the new version is much better but the new design is not as beautiful as the old version.